# Cannot use css property content: "\f111" in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-awesome, css-content

I'm sure that css code is correct. But Firefox cannot understand and display it.

Here is case 1 within css:

```css
.fa-circle:before {
    content: "\f111"
}
```

[image]

and here is another case:

```css
.fa-group:before,
.fa-users:before {
    content: "\f0c0"
}
```

[image]

Can you tell me how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Ensure the `i` and `span` elements' `font` property is set to `normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;` and not being overridden by something else.

Comment: which version of *font-awesome* are you using ?
as its working fine for **4.4.0**

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay I'm using version 4.2.0

Comment: @Kevin here check [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/rk6of925/3) this on your version of *Firefox* as its working fine in mine

Comment: Why are you using `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`?

Comment: I was talking to OP.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Wow. it's working. but, can you tell why doesn't it work on my site? something is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: As @BramVanroy asked you already you're using *bootstrap.css* as well as *bootstrap.min.css* both at once, May be i.e. the issue.

Comment: @BramVanroy Oh, sorry. But, you mean that: something in `bootstrap.css` can be overridden by anything in `bootstrap.min.css`?

Comment: ´bootstrap.min.css` is the *minified* (min) version of `bootstrap.css`. So it is useless to load both files. Only load the minified version.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like your pseudo-element's containers (the `i` and `span` elements) are having their `font` properties overridden by something else.

In Firefox's element inspector you should see the following inherited styles:

[image: Example]

Importantly the `font-family` property should *not* have a line through it - if it does, it means the font being used isn't Font Awesome. If that is the case you'll instead see:

[image: Example 2]

If this is the case, the font being used isn't Font Awesome and the requested character code doesn't exist in the other font's character set.

Comment: only `body font-family` was overridden: `body { font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }`. So, `FontAwesome` is working

Comment: @Kevin that's on the pseudo-element and not just the `.fa`, right?

Comment: I see. I will check it again